# JOIN with multiple OR in HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, nativequery

Below is a SQL query with multiple joins and conditions which gives the desired output, I want to convert the below query to HQL

```
select * from customer c 
join customer_geo_rel cg on c.id=cg.customer_id
join geography g on cg.geo_id=g.id   
join geo_geo_hierarchy gghCluster on g.id = gghCluster.geo_id
join geo_geo_hierarchy gghDivision on gghCluster.geo_id = gghDivision.parent_geo_id   
join role_data_rel rdr on gghCluster.geo_id = rdr.permission_data_id OR   
gghDivision.parent_geo_id = rdr.permission_data_id OR   
g.id=rdr.permission_data_id
```

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have done this much so far

select c.name from customer c
join c.custGeoRel cg  
join cg.geography g  
join g.geographyCategory gc  
join g.geographyHierarchy gghCluster  
join gghCluster.parentGeography gghDivision  
join g.roleDataRelList  rdr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem? HQL supports the ON clause for joins and if you use a very old version of Hibernate, you can use the WITH clause like e.g. `.. join g.roleDataRelList rds on ...`

Comment: Can we add ON clause with Collection property using join?

Comment: Yes you can. Just try it out and see for yourself that it works.

Comment: Can we add ON clause with Collection property? If yes then How?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Just do it like e.g. `select ... from Entity e join e.myCollection c on c.attr = 1`